# ArangoDB lost data after primary dbserver breakdown

Tags: database, arangodb

I have 3 nodes in my ArangoDB cluster:

- Node1 Leader,Agent
- Node2 follower
- Node2 follower

And my options:

- replication.automatic-failover true
- cache.size=2576980377
- rocksdb.block-cache-size=2576980377

About 1 million records in each document collection and about 5 million in corresponding edge colletion.

The cluster runs few weeks. The leader down
when i run AQL

```
for i in documentCollection
filter i.edgeKey != null 
let next = first(
    for n in documentCollection
    filter i.edgeKey == n.edgeKey and i._id != n._id 
    limit 1
    return n
)
filter next != null
upsert{_from:i._id > next._id ? i._id : next._id, _to:i._id > next._id ? next._id : i._id, no:i.edgeKey, type:edgeKey}
insert{_from:i._id > next._id ? i._id : next._id, _to:i._id > next._id ? next._id : i._id, no:i.edgeKey, type:edgeKey, updated:0} 
update{updated: OLD.updated + 1}
in edgeCollection
```

The Node2 elect as leader, but some collection lost all data in it.

**Does it cause by data havn't commit to disk?**

**Can i repair it?**

**And how can i avoid happening again?**

Sorry for my pool english again.

Comment: please run `curl coordinator:port/_api/cluster/agency-dump > agency-dump.json` and add it to your post above.

Comment: Which part is helpful? It's a 704k file.

Comment: Lots of it, I'm afraid. What Database is the collection above in? OK, let's do this: could you provide me with `curl coordinator:port/_db/<dbname>/_api/collection/documentCollection`. That should be just a bit.

Comment: Actually `curl coordinator:port/_db/<dbname>/_api/collection/documentCollection/count`

Comment: the`curl coordinator:port/_db/<dbname>/_api/collection/documentCollection/count`return that `{"error":false,"code":200,"waitForSync":false,"type":3,"globallyUniqueId":"hDC6014105C93/3079540","count":0,"id":"2941342","cacheEnabled":false,"objectId":"2941341","keyOptions":{"allowUserKeys":true,"type":"traditional","lastValue":39239645},"isSystem":false,"name":"edge_5494","status":3,"statusString":"loaded"}`

Comment: this is supposed to be a cluster? I don't see the entry relocationFactor. It needs to be higher than 1. Or else, when you lose a machine that is holding the single replica of your data dies, your data is gone.

Comment: Not `relocationFactor` but `replicationFactor`